# Windows 11 Setup does not recognize NVMe drive in ASUS laptop S513E

Tags: drivers, windows-11, asus-laptop, setup, nvme

I am trying to install Windows 11 on ASUS VivoBook S513E (11th gen Intel) BIOS states the SSD is NVMe Micron 2210 MT

I've downloaded the official drivers from ASUS and unpacked them to their folders:

- GPIO_DCH_Intel_Z_V30.100.2031.2_20227_20221203103154
- I2C_DCH_Intel_Z_V30.100.2031.2_20229_20221203103137
- INFUpdate_DCH_Intel_Z_V10.1.24.5_19906_20221203105000
- SPI_DCH_Intel_Z_V30.100.2031.2_20230_20221203103052
- UART_DCH_Intel_Z_V30.100.2031.2_20228_20221203103036
- VMD_DCH_Intel_Z_V18.4.0.1000_23144_20221203103122
- VMD_DCH_Intel_Z_V18.6.1.1016Sub1_24265_20221203103106

When Windows 11 Setup asks for "Load Driver" dialog ("A media driver your computer needs is missing...") I browse to the unpacked drivers in the USB

When I pick the following folder:

- VMD_DCH_Intel_Z_V18.6.1.1016Sub1_24265_20221203103106

it offers two compatible choices:

1. Intel RST VMD Controller 9A0B
2. Intel RST VMD Managed Controller 09AB

I tried both, (and all the other driver folders I listed above), after a while thinking Windows 11 Setup still reports "No new devices were found..."

**but... something change happens after I install Intel RST VMD driver**:
When I use Shift+F10 to open the console window, and start diskpart after the Intel RST VMD driver I see the NVMe disk  using the 'LIST DISK' command, and before the driver installation it is not there.

**Question**

What driver am I missing?

Comment: https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1044458/